# If I change textbox content I have to double click radio button ASP

Tags: asp.net, textbox, telerik, radiobuttonlist, autopostback

This is what I want for my code. I have textbox that shows like this:

```
<telerik:RadMaskedTextBox ID="txtOccurrenceTime" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFFCC" Width="50px" OnTextChanged="txtOccurrenceTime_TextChanged" Mask="##:##" AutoPostBack ="true"></telerik:RadMaskedTextBox>
```

When you hit enter is all good but when I select one of the radio buttons, it's not actually getting the value and forces the user to double click on it to make it work. This radio button list has a "OnSelectedIndexChanged" event and are "AM" and "PM" items and calculates full time in another box as string (for example 02:03 AM).

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblOccurrenceTimeAMPM" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblOccurrenceTimeAMPM_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack ="true">
   <asp:ListItem Text="AM" Value="AM"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="PM" Value="PM"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I tried to set AutoPostBack = false on the textbox and if you hit enter after you change the text on the textbox, of course nothing happens.

Is there a way I can have the "hit enter option" and "select radio button" only once and have the same results? Please let me know.

Thanks!!!

Comment: If you are using AJAX, try disabling it. At least make sure the radio buttons are included in it.
Also, consider using a RadTimePicker control: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/timepicker/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'm not using AJAX and I have to check first with client with that utility. I'm considering using Javascript too. I'll let you know soon. Thanks!

Comment: If you would still need help with that, post more of your code so we can paste it in a page and reproduce the problem, otherwise it is all guesswork.